# Essentially self adjoint operators definition equivalences

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Quick question about this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4015173/essentially-self-adjoint-operators-a-verification-procedure). If I recall correctly, $T$ being essentially self-adjoint means that its closure is self-adjoint. In other words, we have $\text{cl}(T)^* = \text{cl}(T)$. However, in this post they are claiming that $T$ being essentially self-adjoint is the same as $T^* = \text{cl}(T)$. How is this true? I can see why $T^*$ is an extension of $\text{cl}(T)$, but not necessarily the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $T$ is densely defined and closable (aka has a closure), we have $T^{**} = \text{cl}(T)$ and $T^*$ is closed, thus:
$$T^* = \text{cl}(T^*) = (T^*)^{**} = (T^{**})^* = (\text{cl}(T))^*$$
This can be seen in theorem VIII.1 of *Functional Analysis* by Reed and Simon for example.

Comment: So is there a typo in the original post since they have $T^* = \text{cl}(T)$?

Comment: No, that means that $T$ is essentially self-adjoint iff $T^* = (\text{cl}(T))^* = \text{cl}(T)$, since there is no difference between $T^*$ and $(\text{cl}(T))^*$.